# Text not instantiating under a canvas (unity)

Tags: unity, gui

Below is my code for a text I want to spawn under a canvas. Both spawn and I no longer get errors, but the text isn't spawning under the canvas.

```
        Instantiate(canvasparent);
        Text savescore = Instantiate(score) as Text;
        savescore.transform.SetParent(canvasparent.transform, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to capture a reference to the instance of the object when you instantiate it, something like this:

```
Canvas canvasInstance = Instantiate<Canvas>(canvasPrefab);

Text scoreTextInstance = Instantiate<Text>(scoreTextPrefab);

scoreTextInstance.transform.SetParent(canvasInstance.transform, false);
```

The code you showed is trying to parent the newly-spawned text to the *prefab* of the canvas, not the *instance* of the canvas you've spawned into your scene.

This is probably the most common error I see in Unity code, so be very careful to keep track of which variables refer to spawned instances and which to prefabs.

Comment: Right, so i had to just do what i did in the second line in the first, thanks

Comment: but then i get these errors

Comment: Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.GameObject' expression to type `UnityEngine.Canvas'

Comment: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate<UnityEngine.Canvas>(UnityEngine.Canvas)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Declare `canvasPrefab` as type `Canvas` instead of `GameObject` Also`scoreTextPrefab ` as type `Text` instead of `GameObject`. Then assign them again in inspector.